# How do I get rid of missing sources?

Tags: raspbian, apt

How do I get rid of erring sources:

```
Err:9 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:11 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie/main Translation-en_GB.UTF-8
Ign:12 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Fetched 94.5 kB in 5s (16.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://dev2day.de/pms jessie Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://dev2day.de/pms/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I want to get rid of erorring source list items, I opened 
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
and even
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`
but I cannot find erroring  https source lists !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to fetch https://dev2day.de/pms/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages HttpError404](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103739/failed-to-fetch-https-dev2day-de-pms-dists-jessie-main-binary-armhf-packages-h)

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list`, and remove the line referring to dev2day

Comment: I tried but things got much worst now https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/103787/49991

Answer (score 0):

Try 
apt install --fix-missing
or 
apt update --fix-missing

I have found these commands useful so far.