# Failed to fetch https://dev2day.de/pms/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages HttpError404

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt, update

I'm trying to do a simple `sudo apt-get update` on my Raspberry Pi 2,
but I keep getting 404 error:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   https://dev2day.de/pms/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages 
>   HttpError404
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

My source.list file containes the following repo:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

and I have Jessie version of Raspbian installed.

I tried changing the repo to the newest version (stretch), but didn't solve the problem.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Jessie is **obsolete** and unsupported. It has had NO updates for years and never will.

Comment: @Milliways ok thanks. I will update Raspbian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plex media server has shut down the repository at `https://dev2day.de/`. They have moved to `https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb`. [This page](https://support.plex.tv/articles/235974187-enable-repository-updating-for-supported-linux-server-distributions/) provides the installation instructions, in essence, you need to run:

```
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

I have no idea if they support Jessie though.

Comment: Looking at the error msg the problem seems to be in the 'pms' (hat's probably plex media server) source list, not the Raspbian one

Comment: @Dirk I have plex media server installed

Comment: @amicoderozer Then I would check if there's a source entry in sources.list or a pms list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. At a guess I would say the PMS Jessie repo was removed resulting in the error msg.

Comment: @Dirk You are right, I have this entry in `pms.list` file: `deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ jessie main`

Comment: @amicoderozer Then you should remove it.