# Why apt-get update erroring?

Tags: update

I am getting the following error message

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch InRelease
  Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease               
Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Reading package lists... Done             
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `Could not resolve host: deb.nodesource.com` and `Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'` and `Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'` ... could be a **temporary** problem with the DNS servers you're using

Comment: A good way to test if it's a DNS issue is to try `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8`. If the first doesn't work but the second does, then it's likely a DNS issue.

Comment: Yes i cannot ping google.com i get the same error message. I had pivpn and pihole installed on that raspberry pi , in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` i have commented the line `listen-address127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.4` and rebooted but still i am getting the same problem

Comment: I discovered something inserted `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf` and changing nameserver to point to the router ip `192.168.1.1`  fixed the issue. But i don’t know what inserted entry to resolv.conf file.

Comment: after rebooting raspberry pi the /etc/resolv.conf again got reset to `name server 127.0.0.1` . I don't know what is reset it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cannot ping google.com i get the same error message. I had pivpn and pihole installed on that raspberry pi , in /etc/dnsmasq.conf i have commented the line listen-address127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.4 and rebooted but still i am getting the same problem

I learned that pi-hole was to blame,

It inserted nameserver 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf and changing nameserver to point to the router ip 192.168.1.1 fixed the issue.

1
the resolv.conf was being overwritten by pi-hole from its syatemd service startup. I changed ip address there. But I do not know why they have it setup like this .

Comment: pi-hole assumes by default that the DNS server is running on the local machine. You have to configure it as you did.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is overwritten when your RPi receives a DHCP lease from the server. This could be a misconfigured gateway / router with DHCP, or perhaps you run both a DHCP client and a DHCP server on your RPi.

In general, a way to make `/etc/resolv.conf` user editable is to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and forbid dynamic updates, assuming that this is what you really need. As I said above, you likely need to fix the DHCP server configuration instead.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, the resolv.conf was being overwritten by pi-hole from its syatemd service startup. I changed ip address there. But ‍♂️ why they have it setup like this